# How to get all files and directories from the SVN repository using java

Tags: java, svnkit

I have a task to complete. I Want to connect to SVN repository and have to download all directories and files from svn to my local system using java code. I am new to this and trying to use example to read single file content from http://svnkit.com/kb/dev-guide-commit-operation.html but it is giving  exception like error while fetching the file contents and properties: svn: E170001: Authentication required for 'https://netspurt.unfuddle.com:443 Unfuddle Subversion Repository'. Please anybody can explain it detail

bellow code worked for me:

```
private static SVNClientManager ourClientManager;
     public void DownloadWorkingCopy(String svnLocation,String svnUserName,String svnPassword){

String locationForSVNProj="C:\\SVNLOC";

        DefaultSVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
        ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options, svnUserName, svnPassword);
        SVNUpdateClient updateClient = ourClientManager.getUpdateClient( );
        updateClient.setIgnoreExternals( false );
        SVNRevision rev=SVNRevision.HEAD;
        File file=new File(locationForSVNProj);
        try{
             long revision1=updateClient.doCheckout( SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(svnLocation) ,file , rev , rev , true);

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


    }
```

Comment: Code please, how do you expect people to help you with the code when you don't share the code.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are setting up the authentication to the server at least?

Comment: Sorry I did it forgot to update here It is easy. I updated the working code above. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Authentication required" problem means that the server requires authentication but you didn't provide correct `ISVNAuthenticationManager` implementation to `SVNClientManager`. SVNKit supports different ways of authentication.

If you know what your credentials are, and they are fixed, you can use `BasicAuthenticationManager` implementation.

If you want to use credentials, stored in your `~/.subversion` directory, use `DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager` implementation (there's a convenient method to construct it:`SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager()` but note that this corresponds to Subversion commands with `--non-interactive` option). Look at SVNCommandEnvironment#createClientAuthenticationManager() implementation if you need authentication manager that would allow to enter password from console.

And finally I'd like to notice that SVNClientManager is a part of obsolete (though still supported). Instead prefer SvnOperationFactory class like in my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537849/how-to-download-entire-project-from-svn-repository-using-svnkit-from-java/16567134#16567134), it also has setAuthenticationManager() setter.

I'm one of SVNKit developers if this matters.

Comment: can you please have a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883908/svnkit-authentication-always-fails

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on Dmitry Pavlenko's answer:

```
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNDepth;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.ISVNAuthenticationManager;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNClientManager;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil;

import java.io.File;

private static void obtenerCodigoFuenteSVN() {        
    final String url = "http://IPSVN:PORT/svn/PROJECT";
    final String destPath = "PATH_DIR_DOWNLOAD";

    final String user = "XXXX";
    final String password = "XXXX";

    SVNRepository repository = null;

    try {
        //initiate the reporitory from the url
        repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url));
        //create authentication data
        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(user, password.toCharArray());
        repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        //output some data to verify connection
        System.out.println("Repository Root: " + repository.getRepositoryRoot(true));
        System.out.println("Repository UUID: " + repository.getRepositoryUUID(true));
        //need to identify latest revision
        long latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();
        System.out.println("Repository Latest Revision: " + latestRevision);

        //create client manager and set authentication
        SVNClientManager ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
        ourClientManager.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        //use SVNUpdateClient to do the export
        SVNUpdateClient updateClient = ourClientManager.getUpdateClient();
        updateClient.setIgnoreExternals(false);
        updateClient.doExport(repository.getLocation(), new File(destPath),
                SVNRevision.create(latestRevision), SVNRevision.create(latestRevision),
                null, true, SVNDepth.INFINITY);

    } catch (SVNException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR TO ACCESS REPOSITORY");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

And this is the dependency in maven POM file:

```
   <dependency>
          <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
          <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.11</version>
   </dependency>
```