# how to download entire project from SVN repository using SVNKit from java

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am able to read a contents from SVN repository file by file using SVN kit. But my requirement is to download entire project from SVN repository to my local directory Using SVN kit java code for source code analysis. So How can I achieve this. I have seen examples regarding reading files and directories not downloading projects. Please any one can help me

Comment: Isn't that more or less exactly what you asked earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536149/how-to-get-all-files-and-directories-from-the-svn-repository-using-java

Comment: ya but i am able to find connection to svn repository and able to get file contents. Till that it suggestion worked fine. But for downloading I am spending time but unable to get example samples

Comment: From the SVNKit web site: http://wiki.svnkit.com/Managing_A_Working_Copy

Comment: Thank you Gilbert Le Blanc it worked for me. You saved my time

Answer (score 0):

SVNClientManager is a part of old SVNKit API. As SVNKit developer, I would recommend you to  prefer new SVNKit API based on SvnOperationFactory class (because the old API is implemented via the new one and for some API classes this API-to-API conversion caused problems):

```
final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
try {
    final SvnCheckout checkout = svnOperationFactory.createCheckout();
    checkout.setSource(SvnTarget.fromURL(url));
    checkout.setSingleTarget(SvnTarget.fromFile(workingCopyDirectory));
    checkout.run();
} finally {
    svnOperationFactory.dispose();
}
```

If you don't need ".svn" directories, use SvnOperationFactory#createExport method instead.